# Retorno de Query - Repositório Genérico Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

tenho um repositório genérico e percebi que está demorando muito para retornar uma query com a seleção de algumas colunas do meu banco de dados, o método Query() é o seguinte:

```
public IList<T> Query(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> Where)
    {
        return Entity.AsExpandable().Where(Where).AsQueryable<T>().AsNoTracking<T>().ToList();
    }
```

Se observarem no final eu ainda uso Take(10), mas analisando o código, tem um campo chamado 'source' que mostra 17822 registros, então independente de selecionar 10 ou 1000, me parece que está sempre trazendo todos os registro, segue imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha dúvida é se estou com alguma configuração do entity para sempre ter este comportamento ou a chamada da minha query está errada?

Obrigado

Léo

Comment: onde você está usando o `Skip` e `Take`, antes ou depois do`ToList`?

Comment: Estou usando take depois do ToList

Comment: Quando você usa o `ToList` ele traz o resultado, filtrando depois com `Take`, por isso está trazendo "tudo". Você pode deixar o `ToList` para o final para resolver isso

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basicamente o seu problema é que quando você utiliza o `skip` e `take` depois do `toList()`, o EF já foi ao bd, trouxe todos esses registros, e o `skip` e `take` estão acontecendo em memória.

Entendo que você precise de fazer seu `take(10)`, fora do repositório, então sugiro a seguinte modificação na sua função:

```
public IQueryable<T> 
Query(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> Where)
{
    return Entity.AsExpandable().Where(Where).AsNoTracking<T>();
}
```

- Retiramos o `.AsQueryable<T>()`, pois `AsNoTracking<T>(), já te retorna`Queryable(T)`. isso já te ajuda um pouco do desempenho.
- Retiramos o `ToList()`, para que o EF, não vá ao banco de dados neste exato momento, apenas estamos criando a sua *Query*, que será retornada. Assim você faria o uso da *Query* da seguinte maneira:

---

```
var resultadoDaQuery = Query(seyWhere).Skip(skipRows).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

- Neste momento, quando utilizamos o método `ToList()`, o EF vai ao banco de dados, trazendo apenas os registros, considerando o seu `Skip()` e `Take()`.

Comment: Uma outra forma de explicar a diferença é: no LINQ existem alguns comandos que de fato executam a consulta e traz pra memória (ToList, First, Last, Count), de resto, o objeto vai ser IQueryable, ou seja, apenas uma query que, enquanto não receber um dos comandos citados acima, não é executada no banco.. Ou seja, você primeiro manipula sua query, filtra, agrupa, acrescenta e por fim, executa.

Comment: Ótima observação @M.Bertolazo

Comment: @RodrigoK.B Se o retorno do método for `IList<T>` não vai fazer nenhuma diferença. A query vai ser executada do mesmo jeito.

Comment: @LINQ obrigado pela observação, foi falta de atenção minha. Vou corrigir.